# Spacy pattern matcher. What does "IN" mean?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

How do I interpret the following pattern that is added to the spacy matcher?

```
patterns = [
        [{
            "POS": "ADJ",
            "IS_PUNCT": False
        }],
        [{
            "POS": {
                "IN": ["ADJ", "NOUN"]
            },
            "OP": "*",
            "IS_PUNCT": False
        }, {
            "POS": "NOUN",
            "IS_PUNCT": False
        }],
```

Comment: `POS` tag string is either `"ADJ"` or `"NOUN"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that each dictionary represents one spacy token. First list will match token that has `POS` tagged as `ADJ` and is not punctuation. Second list will match token that has `POS` tagged either as `ADJ` or 'NOUN'. `IN` is comparison attributes which checks if the value is in the list or not. `OP` keyword is quantifier, specifically `*` allows pattern to be matched zero or more times, like in regex. From these examples you can understand other ones and you can read more about matching [here](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching).

Comment: Does the second element in patterns list say that it should be  [ADJ OR NOUN] followed by another NOUN?

Comment: No. it is separate dictionary, so it will be treated as separate token by spacy. Also, If first token is matched [`ADJ` or `NOUN`] and token is `NOUN`, second dictionary token will be matched separately also.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes-extended), 'IN' matches, if POS of the second token is a member of the given list. It is comparable to the 'in' keyword in python.